# how to force angular2 to create an instance of a provider?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I did a service that some observers needs to subscribe to get some data. The problem is that the service is not in a constructor so the instance is never created ! How to force that or is there another way to do this ? I'm using Event of the IONIC2 framework. I can add the Class in the constructor even if I don't use it, but maybe there is a best solution. thanks in advance.

```
import {Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import {log, PRIORITY_INFO, PRIORITY_ERROR} from "./log";
import { BackgroundGeolocation } from 'ionic-native';
import Timer = NodeJS.Timer;
import {Platform, Events} from "ionic-angular";

@Injectable()
export class BackgroundGeolocationService {

    trackerInterval: Timer;
    locations: any;

    constructor(private platform: Platform, public trace: log, private events: Events) {
        this.trace.info('create BackgroundGeolocationService');

        if (this.platform.is('android')) {
            this.platform.ready().then(() => {

                this.trace.info(`platform android ready` );

                // BackgroundGeolocation is highly configurable. See platform specific configuration options
                let config = {
                    interval: 1000,
                    locationTimeout: 100,
                    desiredAccuracy: 10,
                    stationaryRadius: 20,
                    distanceFilter: 30,
                    debug: true, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
                    stopOnTerminate: false // enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
                };

                BackgroundGeolocation.configure((location) => {
                    this.trace.info(`configure  ${location.latitude},${location.longitude}`);

                    this.setCurrentLocation(location);
                    this.startTrackingInterval();

                    // IMPORTANT:  You must execute the finish method here to inform the native plugin that you're finished,
                    // and the background-task may be completed.  You must do this regardless if your HTTP request is successful or not.
                    // IF YOU DON'T, ios will CRASH YOUR APP for spending too much time in the background.
                    //BackgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY

                }, (error) => {
                    this.trace.error(error);
                }, config);

                // Turn ON the background-geolocation system.  The user will be tracked whenever they suspend the app.
                BackgroundGeolocation.start();

            }).catch(err => {
                this.trace.error(err);
            });

        }
    }

    startTrackingInterval(): void {
        this.trackerInterval = setInterval(() => { this.refreshLocations(); }, 2000);
    }

    refreshLocations(): void {
        BackgroundGeolocation.getLocations().then(locations => {
            this.locations = locations;
            if (locations.length != 0) {
                this.setCurrentLocation(locations[locations.length-1]);
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            this.trace.error(`BackgroundGeolocationService error ${error}`);
        });
    }

    startTracker(): void {
        BackgroundGeolocation.deleteAllLocations();
        BackgroundGeolocation.start();
    }

    setCurrentLocation(location: {latitude:string, longitude:string}) {
        this.events.publish('BackgroundGeolocationService:setCurrentLocation', location);
    }

    stopTracking(): void {
        clearInterval(this.trackerInterval);
        BackgroundGeolocation.getLocations().then(locations => {
            this.locations = locations;
            if (locations.length != 0) {
                this.setCurrentLocation(locations[locations.length-1]);
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            this.trace.error(error);
        });
        BackgroundGeolocation.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code so we can get a better idea of your problem.

Comment: you can look https://github.com/prolland006/ionic2_test_plugin/blob/master/src/services/background-geolocation-service.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enforce it by adding a `APP_INITIALIZER` provider that depends on it

```
{ provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (config: BackgroundGeolocationService) => () => Promise.resolve(null),
      deps: [BackgroundGeolocationService], 
      multi: true }
```

Comment: very interresting thanks :). But! I think I'm going to use Observers it can be better to manage errors. With the Events from IONIC2 if there is an error the observer receives nothing and didn't know why.

Comment: No idea what you mean. I don't know Ionic at all. All this does is to create a new instance of the `BackgroundGeolocationService` at application startup.